# How to Change Fields

Tags: lightning

How do I change Fields in these boxes. See image. Thank you !!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields pointed out in the image can be changed at the page layout level.
You can go to the page layout level and then to a related list, for example on 'Quest' related list and modify the columns there. Point to note here will be in Lightning not all the 10 columns are shown in the related list so one will have to rearrange the column positions in order to be shown on the Lightning UI.

Comment: Thank you Very Much. Worked a treat.